# How can I count the number of public keys that can access an SSH account?

Tags: server, ssh, 20.04

How can we count the number of public keys that have been granted access to an SSH account?

Comment: Like viewing the contents of `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of keys that were granted access to a given account, try

`wc -l ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

You can use the tilde path to point to a specific account's home directory ( ~federico, ~zozzi, etc).